# Create folder with MC Access and save MS Word Doc In Folder based on field in form

Tags: vba, file, ms-access, ms-word, save

I have a form that generates  a folder named from a field on the form called "JobName", it then saves that folder to a specific path.  After the folder has been created, I then use the same MS Access form to create a MS Word document.  I need to automatically save that document to the folder  that was created based on the form name "JobName".

This is what I have tried.

```
Dim pStr As String
pStr = Me.JobName

Debug.Print "F:\Job File\01 Bidding\pStr\" & Me.JobName & ".docm"

wd.SaveAs ("F:\Job File\01 Bidding\pstr\" & Me.JobName & ".docm")
```

It returns this in the Immediate window based on a "JobName" called Test

```
F:\Job File\01 Bidding\pStr\Test
```

Comment: What is your question? What is your issue whith that code? Any Errors? What does it do vesus what did you expect? What is `wd`, the relevant code for that is missing?

Comment: The string you showed as from immediate window cannot be right: you are missing the extension .docm you passed to it. Please revise your question.